# php strpos function add values

Tags: php

This is my function

```
<?php
    function checkname($arr, $name) {
        foreach (array_slice(func_get_args(), 1) as $name) {
            if (strpos($arr, $name) !== false) {
                return $name;
            }
        }
        return '';
    }
?>
```

So I could use it this way,

`$_val = checkname($arr[$i], 'image1', 'image3', 'image2'........);`

however if I make a variable like

```
$newVal = “image1”，“image3”，“image2”，“stores1”，“stores2”，“stores”，“stores3”，“stores4”，“design1”，“design2”
```

`$_val = checkname($arr[$i], $newVal);` this way doesnt work, wont get any result or `$newVal` has to be an array?

Comment: Because the syntax for `$newVal` is not valid. Use an array for this purpose (+ maybe `call_user_func_array()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array to pass the values to the function:

```
function checkname($arr, $names) {
    foreach ($names as $name) {
        if (strpos($arr, $name) !== false) {
            return $name;
        }
    }
    return '';
}

print_r(checkname($arr[$i], array('image1', 'image3', 'image2'));
$newVal = array('image1','image3','image2','stores1','stores2','stores','stores3','stores4','design1','design2');
print_r(checkname($arr[$i], $newVal));
```